# Pytorch Lightning manual GPU control

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have a training pipeline with two very big models, such that a single GPU can only fit one of them. I have access to two GPUs, and I decided to put each of the models on its own device. I have implemented all the necessary device changes in the forward pass, and it works fine until I try to train it with Pytorch Lightning - the Trainer class overrides all custom control of devices and moves everything wherever it sees fit.

**Is there a way to disable the automatic GPU management in Pytorch Lightning?** I would like to use it for my project because of the other nice utilities (logging, checkpointing, gradient accumulation, etc), but I'm starting to think I need to ditch it and write a custom training loop.

I tried setting accelerator=None in the Trainer init, but that just moves my models to cpu when I call fit(). I can't find anything in the documentation, and ChatGPT is no help either. I even had a look at the source code of pytorch_lightning.Trainer but the code is too abstract for me.

Comment: Can you include the code that raises the error (probably the `Trainer` `class` and the training loop on which it iterates)? When I write custom PyTorch Lightning models I load them onto the `device` the same way as I would with a regular torch model (e.g. `model.to(device='cuda:0')`, then `print(f'GPU is Available: {next(model.parameters()).is_cuda}')`) prints `GPU is Available: True`).